# redefining Go templates: sometimes works, sometimes fails

Tags: go, go-templates

The following Go template processes without error:

```
{{block "A" "hello"}}{{end}}
{{define "A"}}{{.}}{{end}}
```

The output is "hello", as I would expect from reading the documentation.  In contrast, the following template does not parse:

```
{{block "A" "hello"}}A{{end}}
{{define "A"}}{{.}}{{end}}
```

Here I get the error message

```
template: multiple definition of template "A"
```

Why does the second template give an error while the first does not?  Is this difference intended?

Complete code is here: https://play.golang.org/p/CNAqllVLjB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the doc of [`html/template.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Parse):

> [...] **It is an error if a resulting template is non-empty** (contains content other than template definitions) **and would replace a non-empty template with the same name.** (In multiple calls to Parse with the same receiver template, only one call can contain text other than space, comments, and template definitions.)

Your first template works because `{{block "A"}}` defines an empty template, and so it is allowed to be re-defined.

Your second template fails because `{{block "A"}}` defines a non-empty template and yet you try to re-define it with a non-empty template.

**One thing to note here:** I quoted the doc from the [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package, which should be "identical" to [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/). It is most of the time, but [`text/template.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Parse) is different, and leaves out this important detail, but they work the same way. This is a documentation inconsistency, filed an issue which can be tracked here: [issue #17360](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17360).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the html/template documentation.  I am still missing something, though: the example for `{{block}}` in the documentation replaces a nonempty template with another one, code is here https://play.golang.org/p/cPuVy7im5J .  Given that this works, the text should probably be "would replace a non-empty template with the same name *defined in the call to `Parse()`*" or similar?

Comment: @jochen Yes, you're right, documentation is a little misleading here. But hey, the doc explains 1 call of `Parse()` (except the last, parenthesized part whose phrasing  is unclear / misleading for me).